# How to get text in two layered component

Tags: java, swing

Please I hope that do not hurt your eyes after see the one... so sorry..
I want to get a text as I mentioned above.

Let's have a look at my terrible drawing...
[image]
 What I want to do is :

I want to get the text from the yellow highlighed box.

I designed my program that I need to get few like the above. I used getComponentCount() to check how many labels there are. It is showing correctly and then I used getComponent(int n) , n = 0, and I was looking for getText().. but there is not.

Always thank you.

Comment: Design your code to provide you better access to the information which is been generated, either through a shared model and getters of some kind

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Thank you. I think the only way is redesign ... OTL

Comment: Your drawing is fine.  Save the instance of JLabel1 in a shared model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your design is ok.
getComponent() returns a Component rather than a Label.
You just need to specifically cast it back as a Label:

```
String text = null;
Component c = panel.getComponent(i);
if (c instanceof Label)
    text = ((Label)c).getText();
```

**MVC Approach:**
A more OO solution would be to separate your model (data) from the view (drawing).
You could create a new model Class, let's say "DrawingModel".
Then provide `get()/set()` for every property in the model.
You then connect both by `drawingView.setModel(drawingModel)`.
When you need any data component, you can access or set it from DrawingModel class rather than directly from the View.
The component who actually "drives" the application is called the Controller.

The approach is an architectural pattern called ***Model-View-Controller*** (or MVC in short).
You can learn more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/127624/what-is-mvc-really).

Comment: I appreciate that ,and I'd carefully read thelink you shared.  Have a good day !

Comment: @SengJoonHyun, You're most welcome. It was refreshing to see someone who actually presents some prototyping rather than dump code and ask "what's wrong here?" :)